# getting the item under the cursor when the cursor is clicked in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a google chrome extension, and for my application I need to find the html DOM object that is under the cursor when it is clicked, like the one I can see in the chrome developer tools (but in the exact opposite sense i.e : in the chrome developer tools, when I hover over the source code, the object on the web page gets highlighted, but I want to get the html object when I hover over the object on the web page). Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Comment: @Teepeemm I asked in my answer whether I should delete this question or not since I found the answer to my question in the question exactly posted by you in your comment

Comment: If I understand things correctly, me flagging this as a duplicate created the comment, and triggered the box for you to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Even all these years later, the question is still incorrectly marked as a duplicate. You cannot get the event from a chrome extension...